# Creating Python modules from an extension with extra C data structures

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm working on a custom Python loader that creates Python modules from a particular kind of non-Python file, let's call it a "cheese file". I'm writing my project as a C extension module because these "cheese files" need to be processed by a fairly complex C library (and secondarily, as a way to learn about the Python/C API).

When processing a cheese file, the C library allocates some data structures which will need to be deallocated after the Python module object is deleted. My question is, **how can/should I store those C data structures along with the Python module object?**

Some ideas I had:

- What I would have thought was the cleanest option would be to subclass Python's `ModuleType` from C and adding a field into the subclass to store the data structures. The [extension types tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html#subclassing-other-types) is apparently quite clear about how to subclass a built-in Python type in C, so I expected to be able to do something like this:

  ```c
  typedef struct {
      PyModuleObject module;
      struct cheese_data* data;
  } PyCheeseModule;

  static PyTypeObject PyCheeseModule_Type = {
      PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
      .tp_basicsize = sizeof(PyCheeseModule),
      .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
      .tp_base = &PyModule_Type,
      /* other fields */
  };
  ```

  But `PyModuleObject` is not exposed as part of the Python/C API, so I can't use it in this way.
- I also considered dynamically allocating a [`PyModuleDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef) for each cheese module, and using [`PyModule_FromDefAndSpec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef) along with [`PyModule_ExecDef()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_ExecDef) to create and execute the actual module. But I'm not really sure if `PyModuleDef` is supposed to be used this way, since the documentation only demonstrates it with statically-defined C extension modules, and anyway I would have to deallocate the `PyModuleDef` object itself which kind of brings me back to the same problem.
- Yet another approach is to wrap the C data structure in a Python object and just add it to the module's dict. But then there's a risk that Python code would change or unset that attribute. I suppose I can find a way to work around that, but it seems pretty inelegant.
- Maybe I should just be using Cython for this project. But even so, if this problem is solvable in Cython, it should also be *possible* to do it using the plain old Python/C API, and at least for educational value I'd like to know how.

If necessary, I can expand on these attempts with some additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

### Use a heap type instead of a module?

It's reasonably likely that you don't actually need a module object. Module objects have two main features - they have a `__name__` and they have a modifiable namespace (i.e. a `__dict__`) but those can be fulfilled by any extension type.

In most of the places in Python that you'd typically expect to return a module it isn't actually required: you can return any type during the module initialization process, and you can add any type to `sys.modules`.

The main advantage (for you) of a generic heap type of a module is that heap types don't need a `PyModuleDef` which exists for their lifetime - the spec that they're created with is copied across by `PyType_FromSpec` (and related functions) so only needs to exist for that function call.

One option would be to create a generic struct just to handle the basics of the type:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD;
    const char* name;
    PyObject* dict;
    struct cheese_data* data;
} BaseStruct;
```

Another variation would be to use a flexible array member as the last member (`char extra_space[];`) and just request extra space when you provide `PyType_Spec.basicsize`.

You can handle the initialization in the `Py_tp_new` slot and the cleanup in the `Py_tp_dealloc` slot (as usually).

Finally you'd provide [`PyMemberDef`s](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMemberDef) for `__name__` and `__dict__` - something like:

```
static PyMemberDef cheese_members[] = {
    {"__dictoffset__", T_PYSSIZET, offsetof(BaseStruct, dict), READONLY},
    {"__name__", T_STRING, offsetof(BaseStruct, name), READONLY},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};
```

This should have most of the behaviour of a module but few of the restrictions.

### Use a module

The module state is designed for storing this kind of extra information in. [PEP-3121](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/#example) gives an example of setting up a module state that I'll attempt to summarize here. I don't think you can use the example directly because I think the order of the fields has changed slightly since the PEP!

You create a struct that you use for the module state

```
typedef struct {
    struct cheese_data* data;
    /* alternatively cheese_data might just be part of the struct
     * rather than dynamically allocated in addition to the struct
     */
} MyModState;
```

In the `PyModuleDef` you specify the [`m_size`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef.m_size) option, typically as `sizeof(MyModState)`. The complication here is that you can't use a static `PyModuleDef` because you're aiming to dynamically create this modules:

```
PyModuleDef *mod_def = malloc(sizeof(PyModuleDef));
struct PyModuleDef mod_def_tmp = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    .m_name = "some name",
    .m_size = sizeof(MyModState),
    /* etc */
};
*mod_def = mod_def_tmp;
```

Initializing the state structure goes in the `Py_mod_exec` slot (assuming you're using multi-phase initialization):

```
static int
my_module_exec(PyObject *m) {
    MyModState* state = (MyModState*)PyModule_GetState(m);
    state->data = malloc(sizeof(struct cheese_data));
    /* etc */
}
```

While cleanup of the state goes is handled by specifying a [`m_free` function](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef.m_free) in the module spec,

```
static void free_module(PyObject* m) {
    MyModState* state = (MyModState*)PyModule_GetState(m);
    free(state->data);
}

/* in the PyModuleDef */
    .m_free = free_module,
/* ... */
```

The final issue is to deallocate the `PyModuleDef` so that it doesn't leak memory. [Looking into the Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0a8ae8a50a0fea3d39ec49b220a5c7a5b70e36f8/Objects/moduleobject.c#L704) you see that the last use for the `PyModuleDef` object is looking up `m_free` and calling that.

Therefore, I believe it should be safe to also deallocate the module def by `free(m->m_def)` within `m_free` (and also to deallocate any parts of that which were dynamically allocated, for example the name strings). However - this seems like a hacky solution so I wouldn't treat it as completely future-proof for all versions of Python.